# polyline width conversion map api v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2, polyline

I need a polyline with a width of 20 feet on a google map to track me.

The width() method is in pixels. I also understand that because google maps uses a mercator projection the pixel to distance ratio will change depending on where I am.

What is out there to work around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Polygon` with fill and without stroke should fit your requirement. Just need to calculate points that create such a shape.

Drawing many `Circle`s with radius equal to 20 ft could also create such effect.

Answer (score 1):

Much more significant than any variation from map projection is how far you are zoomed in/out.

Line width is normally chosen to provide good visibility on screen not to represent a specific dimension.  You would need to continually recalculate the required number of pixels and update the poly line every time the user zoomed in or out.